# Gitlab CI failing to connect to Azure SQL Server on ASP .Net Core APP

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, gitlab-ci

Im currently trying to get my local tests to run on the gitlab ci pipeline.

My pipeline config is as it follows :

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.100-focal-amd64

stages:
    - build
    - test
    
before_script:
    - 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip'

variables:
  project: "HouseM8API/HouseM8API"
  test: "HouseM8API/TestingAPI"

build:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - docker-runner
    only:
        refs:
        - Develop
        - master        
    script:
        - "cd $project"
        - 'dotnet restore'
        - 'dotnet build'
test:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - docker-runner
    only:
        refs:
        - Develop
        - master  
    script: 
        - "cd $test"
        - "dotnet test"
```

My connection string is based on this example :

```
"Server=x-server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=housem8DB;User ID=xUser;Password=xPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

All of my tests running on the pipeline give me this result :

```
Error Message:
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I don't know if this matters but im runing on public shared runners on gitlab.

This is my azure firewall settings :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42sU.png)

Comment: I doubt that the IP that you're running the project on (at gitlanbs) has access to your Azure SQL Database and it's unlikely it should if it's a public one.

Comment: That is an incredibly bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can ref these links to check the Azure SQL firewall:

1. [Lesson Learned #67: Azure SQL Database - SSH, VNET and Firewall](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-67-azure-sql-database-ssh-vnet-and-firewall/ba-p/369180)
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/1014453/proxy-azure-sql-database-with-firewall-enabled-on-ip-range

HTH.